# ggplot geom_bar() and base barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

I'd like to reproduce the following base barplot, using `ggplot2::geom_bar()`.

Toy data :

```
set.seed(314)
dat <- data.frame("Player" = rep(c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5"), times = 2),
                  "Score" = runif(n = 10, 0, 10) * 3)
```

**base barplot** : the variable `Player` is duplicated

```
barplot(height = dat$Score, names.arg = dat$Player)
```

[image: barplot_1]

**geom_bar** : the variable `Player` is grouped

```
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Player, y = Score), stat = "identity")
```

[image: barplot_2]

How to use `geom_bar()` so that the variable is duplicated (and not grouped) ? What am I missing ?

**EDIT :**
I changed the code of the base barplot to reorder the data and make more explicit the difference between the 2 functions : I am not sure that the following plot is reproducible using ggplot2 (without any tricks on the data itself).

```
barplot(height = dat[order(dat$Score, decreasing = TRUE), "Score"],
        names.arg = dat[order(dat$Score, decreasing = TRUE), "Player"])
```

[image: barplot_3]

Comment: Not exactly the same as in the base plot but you can try `ggplot(dat) + geom_col(aes(x = Player, y = Score), position = "dodge2")` Note that `geom_col()` is the same as `geom_bar(..., stat = "identity")`

Comment: thanks. indeed not exactly the same, but it is a start. Noted for `geom_col()`, nice shortcut.

Comment: `dat %>% 
  mutate(Player2 = paste0(Player, 1:10)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Player2, y = Score), stat="identity")` possibly this, but I suspect that it chages the order of bars.

Comment: `Player2` is different across each observations.

Comment: @RLave Nice trick. Using this, I can add another column and reorder the bars : `dat %>% 
  mutate(Player2 = paste0(Player, 1:10),
         ord = 1:10) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Player2, ord), y = Score)) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = dat$Player)`. But that's a lot of tricks... I wonder if there is something less cumbersome...

Comment: Can you elaborate *why* you'd want to achieve this? What's the use case?

Comment: no specific usecase in mind (for now). I was just playing around with `geom_bar()` and was very intrigued that I could not reproduce a very simple base barplot...